# loop through rows of data to submit web form

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Sub AutoLoadAccounts()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.urlhere.com/admin/accounts/create"
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    IE.Document.All("title").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
    IE.Document.All("names").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1")
    IE.Document.All("floor").Value = 30
    IE.Document.getElementById("status").selectedindex = 1
    IE.Document.getElementById("email_state").selectedindex = 1
    IE.Document.All("id").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c1")
    IE.Document.All("years").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("d1")
    IE.Document.All("submit").Click

End Sub
```

The above code I use to populate a web form and submit it. I have around 150 rows of data ranging from A1:D1. I am trying to find a way to loop through the rows 1 by 1 after submitting the form until it reaches the end.

So essentially it will start on the first row and populate the fields from A1:D1, then once complete go down to the next row and do the same for A2:D2. and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to organise your source data.  Using two columns you can record the field name and the required value:

```
    A           B
1   Title       Sample Title
2   Names       Sample Names
3   Floor       Sample Floor
```

To loop:

```
Sub AutoLoadAccounts()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim cRow As Range       ' Current row, used to extract values from Excel.

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.urlhere.com/admin/accounts/create"
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    ' Executes once for each row in the source range.
    For Each cRow In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A3")

        ' Read field name and value from current row.
        IE.Document.All(cRow.Value).Value = cRow.Offset(0, 1)
    Next


    IE.Document.All("submit").Click
End Sub
```

This code could be improved.  At the moment the source range is hard coded (`Range("A1:A3")`).  You could improve this, so the code automatically identifies all completed rows in Excel.  If you are interested research the worksheets [UsedRange object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange.aspx).

**EDIT**
Added example that reads source data from columns, not rows.

```
Sub AutoLoadAccounts_Columns()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim cRow As Range       ' Current row, used to extract values from Excel.

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Navigate "https://www.urlhere.com/admin/accounts/create"
    IE.Visible = True

    While IE.busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    ' Executes once for each row in the source range.
    For Each cRow In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:C1")

        ' Read field name and value from current row.
        IE.Document.All(cRow.Value).Value = cRow.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Next


    IE.Document.All("submit").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I am a bit confused on the organising my source data in the way you suggested as I dont see how I can process 150 different items like this? Wouldn't it make sense to have the field names in separate columns? such as:

     A Title   B: Names    C: Floor and then under these columns have the required data, as i have 150 items of data for each.

For example. The data would be Title: PSE, Name: Jamie: Floor: 2 - submit this form and then move to the next row where the next data is another person to complete the form.

Comment: You can do that way.  It doesn't really matter if you use rows or columns.  Either way, you still need to complete the same number of cells in Excel (300 - 150 names and 150 values).  I'll add the columns version.